# How to return the last updated value from a list of repeated records?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm struggling with this query where I'm trying to get the last updated value (based on the last_mod_date). This is the query I wrote but still not getting the desired result.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS INVESTIGATIVE_ACTION_TABLE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE INVESTIGATIVE_ACTION_TABLE AS(
SELECT DISTINCT t1.POLICY_NBR AS POLICY_ID, 
    TRANS_TYP_DESC AS ACTION_TAKEN, 
    MAX(LST_MDFD_DTM) AS LAST_MOD_DATE, 
    LST_MDFD_USER_ID AS LAST_MOD_USER, 
    MAX(CNTRCT_CNCL_EFCTV_DT) AS CANCEL_EFECT_DATE 

FROM POLICY_DETAILS AS t1
INNER JOIN CANC_EFCTV AS t2
ON t1.POLICY_NBR = t2.POLICY_NBR
WHERE t1.POLICY_NBR LIKE 'A%'
AND CNTRCT_CNCL_EFCTV_DT >= '2022-01-01'
AND LST_MDFD_DTM > '2022-01-01' --This range of date is only for example purposes
GROUP BY POLICY_ID, ACTION_TAKEN, LAST_MOD_USER
ORDER BY LAST_MOD_DATE DESC 
);
```

[This is an example of the result I get when I run the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECWh0.png)

Question is... how can I only get 'RESUME BILLING' since its the last registered record for that ID number?

Thanks in advance for you time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table (preferably text-based) with sample data and one with intended output would help test this, but you'll want to use the `qualify` function. It will appear after your `group by` expression - or more likely you can eliminate that group by expression entirely.

You will want this after the `where` clause:

```
qualify rownumber() over 
(partition by POLICY_ID, ACTION_TAKEN, LAST_MOD_USER
 order by LST_MDFD_DTM desc) = 1
```

This will create window partitions by POLICY_ID, ACTION_TAKEN, and LAST_MOD_USER. In that partition, it will sort the rows in reverse order and qualify only the latest update. In other words, the rows that are not the latest will fail the `qualify` test and not appear in the final result set.

If you need an exact answer rather than a general approach, please edit the question to update with some sample data. Generally when answerers create their own sample data based on the description, it can be off a bit.